# T-SQL: Selecting column from an alternate table when null

Tags: t-sql, join, null

I have the following table, TableA, with data:

```
ID    ColA
0     10
1     null
2     20
```

I have another table, TableB, with the following data.

```
ID    ColB   ColC
1     30     80
1     40     70 
3     50     100
```

I need to select rows in TableA but when ColA in the row is null, I want to retrieve the value of ColB in TableB (if one exists) and use it in place of ColA. If no value in ColB exists, then the value of ColA in the result should be null. The join is done on TableA.ID and TableB.ID. TableB can have multiple rows where the ID column repeats. TableB.ID and TableB.ColC together make a row unique. So my result should look like this if ColC is limited to the value of 70:

```
ID   ColA
0     10 
1     40
2     20
```

Not sure how to do this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.ID, COALESCE(a.ColA, b.ColB) as 'ColA'
from TableA a
left join TableB b on a.ID = b.ID and b.ColC = 70
```

Comment: No, this returns multiple rows with ID 1. Have you tried this?

Comment: @DavidM you are right, if I make it in the `where clause` the problem is solved :)

Comment: Yes, so you now have the same as mine, but using the equivalent `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`. This will work.

Comment: @DavidM indeed, but I've put this one 5m ago and you said it dind't work :P

Comment: Your edit hadn't refreshed. You had a `WHERE` clause in ther version I was typing the comment against. In fact, your previous comment says as much...

Comment: Works with your correction. Considerably less code than the others. Thanks a million! Wasn't aware of the COALESCE function.

Comment: Like @DavidM stated, `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` work here but they make different things :)

Comment: Yes, correct in general. `COALESCE` takes more than two arguments, `ISNULL` just two. For two arguments, they are the same. And @AndroidDev - this code is actually longer than mine, I have just used more whitespace...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want if I have correctly interpreted your question:

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        ISNULL(a.ColA, b.ColB) ColA
FROM    TableA a
        LEFT JOIN
                TableB b
                ON a.ID = b.ID
                AND b.ColC = 70
```

I have literally "limited to the value of 70" in ColC as you stated.

Comment: Why use the b.ColC in the join instead of a where? I'm just curious. Do they behave differently or is it just a preference thing?

Comment: Yes, they do. If in a `WHERE` clause then: If you have a single matching row in TableB where ColC is not 70, this won't appear in the results. If you have no matching row in TableB, this won't appear in the results.

Comment: Cool. Thx for the explanation. I got called out for using an old style join as opposed to a new once, so I didn't know if this was one of those things. =)

Comment: Sorry, but that does not give the results. I ran your code exactly as you wrote it and ColA comes back with 0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're looking for a case statement.  try `case when TableA.Value is null then TableB.Value end`

[SQL Case Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)